# C# Machine Learning and Multi-label Classification

Tags: c#, machine-learning, classification, accord.net, ml.net

I am an apprentice and I just finished my first .NET web application that main premise is to parse group and visualize logs from ELmah.io(Error Logging Modules and Handlers). I had a look in to ML.NET Model Builder and multi-class classification that would allow me to add a single class to log (for example priority) and train model according to that straight from SQL server tables. What I'm more interest is multi-label classification which ML.NET not support at the moment and I was looking in to Accord.NET and I have to admit it's a bit confusing and very hard to find any tutorials - I was able to run a simple binary classification example from their website, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Any guidance where to start would be appreciated(maybe another alternative to ML.NET?).

From what I've read my table structure would look something like this:

[image]

An example of my front end:

[image]

Thanks,

Jakub

Comment: regarding `multi-label classification which ML.NET not support at the moment`, please see https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/5385#issuecomment-389396820 `The Iris example on the getting started page is a multiclass classifier:` https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/apps/machine-learning-and-ai/ml-dotnet/get-started

Comment: How many classes do you have? You could always use a separate model per class.

Comment: Your idea is very interesting indeed, I will have maximum 5 classes - that would mean 5 separate models?

Comment: 5 models sounds reasonable, each model to separate each class from the rest, then use them in an ensemble model to pick the prediction with the highest confidence.

Comment: Technically if your models are accurate enough, you could use 4 models (similar to how you only need 1 model to distinguish 2 classes) however 5 could be more accurate and I personally prefer symmetrical solutions

Comment: Thinking about it, one could use as few as 3 (ab/cde, ac/bde, ae/bcd). Not suggesting this though :)

Answer (score 0):

ML.net till today does not support Multi-Label Classification.

What you can do instead is to train your model on each label separetly then combine results.